# Double integration on a polar curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I determine the angle limits of integration of a single loop of the rose formed by $r=\cos3\theta$? Say I want to find the area of the loop on the second quadrant.
I know how to perform the integration and why it works, I just can't determine the angle limits. The area is given by $$\int_\alpha ^\beta \int _0 ^{\cos 3\theta}rdrd\theta$$
I suspect that $\alpha=\pi/2$ but I'm unsure.

Edit: my best approximation for $\theta$ is now $$\pi/2\leq\theta\leq 3\pi/3.6$$

Comment: Have you tried setting $\cos(3\theta)=0$ and solving for $\theta$?

Comment: That helped, thank you